# How to add elevation to TabItem?

Tags: android, tabs

Is there any way to achieve this effect in Tablayout where selected tab item have elevation.

[image: screenshot]

Got the results with MaterialButtonToggleGroup, I need to tie it with viewpager so MaterialButtonToggleGroup may cause problems

Comment: Your picture in not clear

Comment: sorry for the low quality image. Actually I need elevation on selected tab item

Comment: Do you want elevation in a card view?

Comment: Nope i need elevation in selected tabitem inside tablayout